# Run container on specific IP with docker python API

Tags: python, api, docker

If I run container from console I execute this command:

```
docker run -d --name iperf_srv --network mynet --ip 10.195.10.10 astotal/iperf3 -s
```

And then I have iperf listening on 10.195.10.10 ip address.

How can I do the same with python API?

There is code which runs container on IP from ipam pool, but it is not actually what I need

```
import docker 

doc = docker.from_env()
srv_pool=docker.types.IPAMPool(subnet='10.195.10.0/24',iprange='10.195.10.0/24')

srv_ipam=docker.types.IPAMConfig(pool_configs=[srv_pool])

doc.networks.create('uplink', driver='macvlan', options={'parent':'eth2.3200'},ipam=srv_ipam)

srv=doc.containers.run('astotal/iperf3', '-s', network='uplink', detach=True, name='iperf_server')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best solution I found with a few inter steps:

```
srv = doc.containers.create('astotal/iperf3', '-s', detach=True, name='iperf_server')
doc.networks.get("uplink").connect(srv, ipv4_address="10.195.10.11")
srv.start()
```